# Admin Django, для telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot, сервер, django-admin

Есть проект, до этого задавала вопросы, но судя по всему сделала это неправильно.
Есть **телеграм бот** написан на **Django**, у этого **бота** есть **админка django**. Я меняю файл для **админки** вношу изменения, но захожу на админку, ничего не меняется. Как мне загружать изменения админки на сервер?

Comment: если меняете админку на локалке, то надо применить изменения  и на сервере. Это можно сделать разными способами, например зайти на сервер и ручками всё поменять, либо использовать синхронизацию с гитом (если она есть), либо улиту по типу `FileZilla` или `PyTTY` и заменить на сервере, те файлы в которых были изменения.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ работала через putty, но изменения не отображаются на сайте. Но я уже разобралась, как с этим работать